# Как в консоли указать начальное значение при вводе?

Tags: c#

Дефолтное значение - это хорошо. Но что, когда дефолтное значение - это длинная строка, а у нее надо изменить 1 символ? Не хотелось бы набирать его вручную полностью (тем более это повышает шанс допустить опечатку)

Есть ли возможность сделать ввод через Console.ReadLine так, чтобы уже было введено какое то значение?

Comment: Перед ReadLine задайте нужное значение.

Comment: @МаксимКутовой И как я смогу его отредактировать?

Comment: @МаксимКутовой, я думаю вопрос в том, чтобы вывести текст в консоль, который пользователь смог бы отредактировать

Comment: Давай так. У меня есть строка такая-то, мне надо чтобы в ней после `ReadLine` изменилось то-то... Подправляй вопрос. Больше конкретики.

Comment: @МаксимКутовой, я все правильно написал, это вы не правильно поняли. представьте, что у вас есть форма и на ней текстовое поле, в которое надо что-то ввести. А значение по-умолчанию в него уже введено. Вы можете его удалить и написать новое или отредактировать, как вам нужно. Вот это же я и хочу получить в консоли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант без [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx), из [аналогичного вопроса на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1655318/how-to-set-default-input-value-in-net-console-app)

```
// write the initial buffer
char[] buffer = "Initial text".ToCharArray();
Console.WriteLine(buffer);

// ensure the cursor starts off on the line of the text by moving it up one line
Console.SetCursorPosition(Console.CursorLeft + buffer.Length, Console.CursorTop - 1);

// process the key presses in a loop until the user presses enter
// (this might need to be a bit more sophisticated - what about escape?)
ConsoleKeyInfo keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
while (keyInfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter)
{

    switch (keyInfo.Key)
    {
         case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                ...
         // process the left key by moving the cursor position
         // need to keep track of the position in the buffer

         // if the user presses another key then update the text in our buffer
         // and draw the character on the screen

         // there are lots of cases that would need to be processed (backspace, delete etc)
    }
    keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: Если вместо **Console.WriteLine(...)** использовать **Console.Write(...)**, то не придется двигать курсор, он просто останется в конце выведенной строки.

Answer (score 3):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write("Your editable text:");
    SendKeys.SendWait("hello"); //hello текст будет редактируемым
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Справка для [SendKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx)

Comment: тут есть одна беда.... мне что, к консольному приложению придется подключать Windows.Forms???

Comment: @iRumba, а почему нет? приложение под _.NET_ это пространство имен стандартное

Comment: @iRumba если вы не любитель легких путей, то можете воспользоваться winapi

Comment: @Grundy, религия не позволяет. WinApi тут было бы более предпочтительно. Но, может есть еще варианты? Неужели консоль (класс Console) сама не умеет такое делать?

Comment: @Grundy, я не смогу объяснить преподу, почему у меня к консольному приложению подключен System.Windows.Forms. Тем более что на самом деле я пишу на c++/cli, а метку c# поставил потому, что с консолью работаю фрэймворковскими средствами (класс Console)

Comment: @iRumba класс консоли не содержит методов для решения данной задачи(да и не должна).

Comment: @iRumba не вижу проблем объяснить, но если вы видите в этом проблему, то [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, Int32 sizeOfInputStructure); вам в помощь.